# Manipulating user data to store in database?

Tags: database, mongodb, data-manipulation

I am creating a workout/exercise logger for users. Currently, I am working on the backend and am storing the data to a mongoDB database/collection. To log the exercise they have done, the application accepts the exercise name as an argument along with other arguments to process and save the user's input to the database. What I have noticed is that if the user was to enter the exercise name in different 'forms' (e.g. 'Squat', 'squat', 'SQUAT', 'SqUaT'), there will be a new entry for that 'form' in the database, which I do not want. Therefore, I thought it would be suitable to use toLowerCase() to convert the user's input to all lowercase so that the exercise name cannot be duplicated in different 'forms', however, I have read that you should leave user data the way it was inputted.

So I am wondering whether it is acceptable to manipulate the data in this case or is there a better way in preventing the duplications?

Comment: There are other ways to prevent duplication. For example you could check before saving the name that a similar name doesn't already exist, using toLowerCase() only in that check. Some other pattern commonly seen is to actually transfor user input as they input it: that way the user sees whatever you will save, and the value saved is not different from what they see

Comment: Depends on the requirements of the application. Do you want to enforce unique exercise names?

Comment: @LaurentS. Thanks for the suggestion. I have not touched the frontend part of the application yet but I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Zack I don't believe it would need unique exercise names, as I can not think of a case of why it would need to be enforced.